# How to allow page refresh/redirect after Ajax POST submission (of Django form)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm a client-side newbie learning the ropes, and need to clarify Ajax concepts.

`e.preventDefault();` is a typical method of preventing form submission (page refresh) in JS.

One use case where the above is handy is Ajax-based form submission. Sample code is:

```
function overwrite_default_submit(e) {
  // block the default behavior
  e.preventDefault();

  // create and populate the form with data
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("reply", text_field.value);

  // send the form via AJAX
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', e.target.action);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", get_cookie('csrftoken'));
  xhr.send(form_data);
}
```

I have two questions:

1) Imagine the `POST` request is being sent to a function that ends with a `redirect` to a different URL. For example, I use Django to develop web applications; a typical Django view may end up with `return redirect("home")` where home is the home page of the said app. In such a scenario, how does `preventDefault()` prevent the `redirect` statement in server-side code from executing? I'm trying to understand the exact mechanics behind it.

2) What if one wanted page refresh (or redirect) *to proceed normally* after an Ajax POST request? What tweaks need to be made? Would love to see an illustrative example to clarify my concepts.

I'm well-versed in Django (Python) so in case you need to show server-side code, Django would be a good example.

*Note: prefer to stick to pure JS for this, since I'm learning JS these days. JQuery's on my radar, but only after I've mastered the fundamentals of JS.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preventDefault()` cancels the event, Default action that event of element will not occur. This will simply halt further execution of javascript code after that statement.

For i.e.
 - Clicking on a `submit` button, prevent it from submitting a form.
 - Clicking on a `link`, prevent the `link` from following the given
   `URL`

To redirect to the next page or to add notification or may be to add html through javascript, but here is to redirect only.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) //Here we need to check OK response and last state of ajax call.
        {
            window.location.href = 'REDIRECT_URL'
            window.location.reload() // To refresh page.    
        }
    };
```

=== I've added that in your function ===

```
function overwrite_default_submit(e) 
{
    // block the default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    // create and populate the form with data
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("reply", text_field.value);

    // send the form via AJAX
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) //Here we need to check OK response and last state of ajax call.
        {
            window.location.href = 'REDIRECT_URL'
            window.location.reload() // To refresh page.    
        }
    };  
    xhr.open('POST', e.target.action);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", get_cookie('csrftoken'));
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(form_data);
}
```

Now in case of Django you need also need to add view / call proper action that should return either json or xml.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def some_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({"key": "value"})
```

To know how ajax work you can check here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Interesting that you added the `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` line before `send`. When I include this line in my code (uncommented), the POST parameters appear as `None` at the Django end. Without that line, they are received correctly. Any theories on that?

Comment: contentType is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the default. In our case it's missing charset. As default already has taken. So no need to add explicitly. It requires in case of json type parameters. If you try with charset it will work. You can also check this in browser console / inspect by using f12 in network tab chrome or FF. Now you can accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Ajax request should not receive redirect response. Usually it  supposed to be a valid json-string. Django has a JsonResponse for this purpose. If you want your django view to process ajax data you should check it on your backend side, for example:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

2) You can do redirect with your javascript code, for instance:

```
window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```